# How to pass the experiment configuration to a SagemakerTrainingOperator while training?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, mwaa

Idea:

- To use experiments and trials to log the training parameters and artifacts in sagemaker while using MWAA as the pipeline orchestrator

I am using the training_config to create the dict to pass the training configuration to the Tensorflow estimator, but there is no parameter to pass the experiment configuration

```
tf_estimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='train_model.py',
                                      source_dir= source
                                      role=sagemaker.get_execution_role(),
                                      instance_count=1,
                                      framework_version='2.3.0',
                                      instance_type=instance_type,
                                      py_version='py37',
                                      script_mode=True,
                                      enable_sagemaker_metrics = True,
                                      metric_definitions=metric_definitions,
                                      output_path=output

model_training_config = training_config(
                    estimator=tf_estimator,
                    inputs=input
                    job_name=training_jobname,
                )
    



training_task = SageMakerTrainingOperator(
                    task_id=test_id,
                    config=model_training_config,
                    aws_conn_id="airflow-sagemaker",  
                    print_log=True,
                    wait_for_completion=True,
                    check_interval=60  
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that i found right now is to use the CreateTrainigJob API (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTrainingJob.html#sagemaker-CreateTrainingJob-request-RoleArn). The following steps are needed:

- I am not sure if this will work with Bring your own script method for E.g with a Tensorflow estimator
- it works with a build your own container approach
- Using the CreateTrainigJob API i created the configs which in turn includes all the needed configs like - training, experiment, algporthm etc and passed that to SagemakerTrainingOperator

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [experiment_config](https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/training/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.EstimatorBase.fit) in estimator.fit. More detailed example can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-sagemaker-experiments-organize-track-and-compare-your-machine-learning-trainings/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply , i need the same for the Airflow operator and not for the estimator.fit function